# OpenGL View using Cocos2d inside a Mac Desktop Application

Tags: xcode, macos, user-interface, opengl, cocos2d-iphone

I'm just getting started in development for a mac desktop app that will aid me in dealing with rigging a 2-D character in cocos2d.

The layout for what I'm working on is in the image here:
[image]

In the big grey rectangle to the right, I'd like to create an active cocos2d scene that I can interact with using the standard mac app GUI on the left. For example, when the user selects a file using the `LOAD CHARACTER IMAGE...` button, I want the scene to add the image as a `CCSprite` on the right. I want them to set the `anchorPoint` by clicking an anchor point button, and then clicking on the sprite, etc...

**My Question is:** How do I start implementing the scene within the window? How do I add the cocos2d framework to my project?

I'm fairly comfortable working strictly within cocos2d,  but I need to get it to interact with a standard desktop GUI.

What steps do I take to get the scene in the window?

******EDIT******

I'm editing this to further clarify my questions that I need answered.

**1. How do I add the cocos2d files to a project without using one of the templates?**

**2. How do I get a cocos2d scene to show up inside the grey rectangle of my .xib? (OpenGLView?)**

Comment: Have a look at the _Cocos2D-With-UIKit-Views-Template_ project in Kobold2D: http://www.kobold2d.com … The basic setup is in there, you only need to move and resize the EAGLView to make room for your GUI elements.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Taking a look at it now.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Thanks for the tip. However, it's a little outside the scope of my question. I'm having trouble sorting through the templates to find which pieces of code are the most relevant to what I'm trying to achieve. It looks like you have a lot of fantastic resources available, and a fantastic product to boot. Do you think you can provide me with a little more specific advice on how to get a cocos2d scene up and running inside my mac app using just cocos2d and interface  builder? Thanks for your time in advance!

Comment: Of course but you'll have to ask me a specific question first (preferably on SO). I'll make sure to answer it ;)